# Word that only includes my father, mother, brother, and sister

Tags: word-request, kinship-terms

Is there any word or term for explaining a group of people including only my father, mother, brother, and sister (excluding my cousin, uncle, and aunty)?

Comment: I would say my **immediate family**. People also speak about **first degree relatives**.     https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_family

Comment: Nuclear family is also possible in this case https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_family

Answer (score 1):

There are two terms you can use for your situation:

*[Immediate Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediate_family):*

> It normally includes a person's parents, siblings, spouse, and children

*[Nuclear Family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_family):*

> A family group consisting of parents and their children (one or more)

Comment: I wouldl not use _nuclear family_ to refer to an actual living family, but only as an abstract description of a kind of household.

Answer (score 0):

Close relatives or Immediate family

[According to Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/immediate%20family)

> Definition of immediate family : a person's parents, brothers and
> sisters, husband or wife, and children. Hospital visits are limited to
> immediate family.